# Override default theme definitions for material UI theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

In the material UI default theme there exist the (css) class `MuiTab-root`. Which, among others, sets the font weight (based on the theme's typography definition).

```
.MuiTab-root {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

This is generated by `withStyles` using `createMuiTheme` function. During creation it uses `typography.fontWeightMedium` of the supplied object to define the font weight of the tabs.
I wish to do is override the `font-weight` of the default theme to be "normal". Ideally by stating it should use `typography.fontWeightNormal`, or failing that, manually overriding the font weight.

I have tried manually overriding the font weight. However this didn't work.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        fontWeightMedium: 600,
    },
    overrides: {
        '.MuiTab-root': {
          fontWeight: 400,
        }
    }
});
```

Inspection using chrome shows the fontWeight of tabs is still 600 (demi bold).

How to override the default definition here? - Or do I have to rely on a custom class I use in the components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax for the manual override:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        fontWeight: 400
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Tab font weight override]

Here's the relevant documentation: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override

Comment: If I override for instance shadows because I want to add a custom shadow, it will prevent me from accessing the other default shadows. Is there a way to add a new shadow but keep the default shadows?